# Putting array into an HTML table and ascending or descending them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting

I'm trying to get a JavaScript array into an HTML table when the page loads, and then when an arrow is clicked (either up or down) it arranges them into ascending or descending order.

Here's the script I have:

```
var lakeData = [
{
    "Month": "1959-01",
    "LakeErieLevels": 12.296
},
{
    "Month": "1959-02",
    "LakeErieLevels": 13.131
},
{
    "Month": "1959-03",
    "LakeErieLevels": 13.966
},
{
    "Month": "1959-04",
    "LakeErieLevels": 15.028
},
{
    "Month": "1959-05",
    "LakeErieLevels": 15.844
},
{
    "Month": "1959-06",
    "LakeErieLevels": 15.769
},
{
    "Month": "1959-07",
    "LakeErieLevels": 15.237
},
{
    "Month": "1959-08",
    "LakeErieLevels": 14.801
},
{
    "Month": "1959-09",
    "LakeErieLevels": 14.137
},
{
    "Month": "1959-10",
    "LakeErieLevels": 13.89
},
{
    "Month": "1959-11",
    "LakeErieLevels": 13.416
},
{
    "Month": "1959-12",
    "LakeErieLevels": 13.871
},
{
    "Month": "1960-01",
    "LakeErieLevels": 14.478
},
{
    "Month": "1960-02",
    "LakeErieLevels": 14.725
},
{
    "Month": "1960-03",
    "LakeErieLevels": 14.763
},
{
    "Month": "1960-04",
    "LakeErieLevels": 15.806
},
{
    "Month": "1960-05",
    "LakeErieLevels": 16.565
},
{
    "Month": "1960-06",
    "LakeErieLevels": 17.097
},
{
    "Month": "1960-07",
    "LakeErieLevels": 17.306
},
{
    "Month": "1960-08",
    "LakeErieLevels": 17.211
},
{
   "Month": "1960-09",
   "LakeErieLevels": 16.717
},
{
   "Month": "1960-10",
   "LakeErieLevels": 15.787
},
{
   "Month": "1960-11",
   "LakeErieLevels": 14.801
},
{
   "Month": "1960-12",
   "LakeErieLevels": 14.231
}
];
```

And here's the little bit of HTML I have:

```
<table id="lake">
  <thead><tr><th>Date</th><th>Average Depth</th></tr></thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

I know it seems simple, but I'm stumped. Again, I'm trying to get the array to load into a table in HTML when the page loads, and then when you click either an up arrow or down arrow, the table arranges either ascending or descending.

Comment: You need three things: a function which sorts your data in ascending or descending order, a function which fills your table body with rows generated from your data and finally the two buttons with onclick event handlers attached.

Answer (score 0):

**Sorting Data**

You can use the array [**Sort**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function to ascending and descending your data(array of objects), something like,

```
/** Sorting the data in asscending  by comparing month **/
function inOrderAsc(a, b){
  return a.Month == b.Month ? 0 : +(a.Month > b.Month) || -1;
}

/** Sorting the data in descending by comparing month **/
function inOrderDesc(a, b){
  return a.Month == b.Month ? 0 : +(a.Month < b.Month) || -1;
}

function accending(objs){
    return objs.sort(inOrderAsc);
 }

function descending(objs){
    return objs.sort(inOrderDesc);
}
```

**Attach the event**

Attach the key down event, on which the sort operation will be performed,

```
/**Attach event, on which the sort action will be performed **/
document.onkeydown = initEvent;
function initEvent(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    if (e.keyCode == '38') {
        var result = accending(lakeData);
        displayData( result);
    } else if (e.keyCode == '40') {
        var result = descending(lakeData);
        displayData(result);
    }
}
```

**Display data**

Now finally display the data after sorting,

```
/** Display the data in table **/
function displayData(objs){
    var row, cell, cell2;
    var tbody = document.querySelector('#lake tbody');
    var cloneTbody = tbody.cloneNode(false);
    tbody.parentNode.replaceChild(cloneTbody, tbody);

    for(var i=0; i<objs.length; i++){
        row = cloneTbody.insertRow();
        cell = row.insertCell();
        cell.innerHTML = objs[i].Month;

        cell2 = row.insertCell();
        cell2.innerHTML = objs[i].LakeErieLevels;
    }
}
```

The full demo is on [**JsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/sumanbogati/Lmhuaedj/).