# How to create loop that populates an HTML table with a Javascript array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, html-table, populate

I've been tasked with populating an HTML table using javascript arrays, but I'm having a lot of trouble understanding how to get my arrays to populate an actual HTML table. I have to create a table that has 5 menu item images, 5 menu item descriptions, and their 5 prices. I have my arrays provided below, but don't know what functions I need to perform to get the arrays to populate the HTML table. What do you recommend I do to get them populating in an HTML table?

Also, as per the assignment, I must use a numeric array to store the prices and a string array to store the image files.

I think I have to perform some kind of 'for' loop, but I'm not sure.

Thanks for all of your help, and please let me know how I can refine this question.

Thanks,

```
//my arrays

var item = ["Chicken soup", "Chicken tacos", "Chicken quesadilla", "Chicken burrito", "Chicken enchilada"];

var itemDescription = ["Delicious creamy chicken soup", "Homemade tacos", "Cheesy chicken quesadillas", "Hearty stuffed chicken burrito", "World famous chicken enchilada"];

var itemPrice = [14.99, 17.99, 15.75, 22.95, 12.55];

var imgArray = new Array();

imgArray[0] = new Image();
imgArray[0].src = 'chickensoup.jpg';

imgArray[1] = new Image();
imgArray[1].src = 'chickentaco.jpg';

imgArray[2] = new Image();
imgArray[2].src = 'chickenque.jpg';

imgArray[3] = new Image();
imgArray[3].src = 'chickenburrito.jpg';

imgArray[4] = new Image();
imgArray[4].src = 'chickenenchilada.jpg';
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Populate an HTML table from javascript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47492355/populate-an-html-table-from-javascript-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters I would recommend merging the arrays into one, to avoid any errors regarding indices.

The standard html format is of the type:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>description</th>
            <th>price</th>
            <th>imageSrc</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Chicken soup</td>
            <td>Delicious creamy chicken soup</td>
            <td>14.99</td>
            <td><img src="chickensoup.jpg" alt="chickensoup.jpg"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

So you need one loop to print all the headers.
You need one loop to create a different row for each item.
You need one last loop inside the row loop to add each cell (food property) to the row.

```js
var items = [{
  name: "Chicken soup",
  description: "Delicious creamy chicken soup",
  price: 14.99,
  imageSrc: "chickensoup.jpg"
}, {
  name: "Chicken tacos",
  description: "Homemade tacos",
  price: 17.99,
  imageSrc: "chickentaco.jpg"
}, {
  name: "Chicken quesadilla",
  description: "Cheesy chicken quesadillas",
  price: 15.75,
  imageSrc: "chickenque.jpg"
}, {
  name: "Chicken burrito",
  description: "Hearty stuffed chicken burrito",
  price: 22.95,
  imageSrc: "chickenburrito.jpg"
}, {
  name: "Chicken enchilada",
  description: "World famous chicken enchilada",
  price: 12.55,
  imageSrc: "chickenenchilada.jpg"
}];

var propertyList = ["name", "description", "price", "imageSrc"];

var table = document.createElement("table");
var tableHeader = document.createElement("thead");
var tableHeaderRow = document.createElement("tr");
var tableBody = document.createElement("tbody");

table.setAttribute("border", "1");

document.body.appendChild(table);
table.appendChild(tableHeader);
tableHeader.appendChild(tableHeaderRow);
table.appendChild(tableBody);

propertyList.forEach(function(key) {
  var headerCell = document.createElement("th");
  tableHeaderRow.appendChild(headerCell);
  headerCell.textContent = key;
});


items.forEach(function(foodItem) {
  var foodRow = document.createElement("tr");
  tableBody.appendChild(foodRow);
  propertyList.forEach(function(propertyName) {
    var foodProperty = document.createElement("td");
    foodRow.appendChild(foodProperty);
    if (propertyName === "imageSrc") {
      var image = document.createElement("img");
      foodProperty.appendChild(image);
      image.src = foodItem[propertyName];
      image.alt = foodItem[propertyName];
    } else {
      foodProperty.textContent = foodItem[propertyName];
    }
  });
});
```

If you cannot merge the arrays then you can use this instead.

```js
var item = ["Chicken soup", "Chicken tacos", "Chicken quesadilla", "Chicken burrito", "Chicken enchilada"];

var itemDescription = ["Delicious creamy chicken soup", "Homemade tacos", "Cheesy chicken quesadillas", "Hearty stuffed chicken burrito", "World famous chicken enchilada"];

var itemPrice = [14.99, 17.99, 15.75, 22.95, 12.55];

var imgArray = new Array();

imgArray[0] = new Image();
imgArray[0].src = 'chickensoup.jpg';

imgArray[1] = new Image();
imgArray[1].src = 'chickentaco.jpg';

imgArray[2] = new Image();
imgArray[2].src = 'chickenque.jpg';

imgArray[3] = new Image();
imgArray[3].src = 'chickenburrito.jpg';

imgArray[4] = new Image();
imgArray[4].src = 'chickenenchilada.jpg';

var foodList = {
  name: item,
  description: itemDescription,
  price: itemPrice,
  imageSrc: imgArray
};

var propertyList = ["name", "description", "price", "imageSrc"];

var table = document.createElement("table");
var tableHeader = document.createElement("thead");
var tableHeaderRow = document.createElement("tr");
var tableBody = document.createElement("tbody");

table.setAttribute("border", "1");

document.body.appendChild(table);
table.appendChild(tableHeader);
tableHeader.appendChild(tableHeaderRow);
table.appendChild(tableBody);

propertyList.forEach(function(key) {
  var headerCell = document.createElement("th");
  tableHeaderRow.appendChild(headerCell);
  headerCell.textContent = key;
});

for (var index = 0; index < item.length; index++) {

  var foodRow = document.createElement("tr");
  tableBody.appendChild(foodRow);
  propertyList.forEach(function(propertyName) {
    var foodProperty = document.createElement("td");
    foodRow.appendChild(foodProperty);
    if (propertyName === "imageSrc") {
      foodProperty.appendChild(foodList[propertyName][index]);
    } else {
      foodProperty.textContent = foodList[propertyName][index];
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Hello nick zoum, your code worked perfectly. I put it into my .js file and it showed up exactly how it was supposed to. Unfortunately, and this is my fault because I did not clarify, I'm tasked with using numeric arrays for the prices string arrays for the image files, so I cannot string all of the arrays into one. Does this make sense? Do you have another recommendation? Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @ImCanaan I added a second example in the answer

Comment: @ImCanaan I'm glad I could help. Please let me know if you need any further explanation regarding the code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
let itemObject = [];

itemObject.push({
    item: 'Chicken soup',
    description: 'Delicious creamy chicken soup',
    price: 14.99,
    image: 'chickensoup.jpg'
});
itemObject.push({
    item: 'Chicken tacos',
    description: 'Chicken taco',
    price: 17.99,
    image: 'chickentaco.jpg'
});
itemObject.push({
    item: 'Chicken quesadilla',
    description: 'Chicken quesadilla',
    price: 15.75,
    image: 'chickenque.jpg'
});
itemObject.push({
    item: 'Chicken burrito',
    description: 'Chicken burrito',
    price: 22.95,
    image: 'chickenburrito.jpg'
});
itemObject.push({
    item: 'Chicken enchilada',
    description: 'Chicken enchilada',
    price: 12.55,
    image: 'chickenenchilada.jpg'
});


let tbody = document.getElementById('tbody');

for (let rows of itemObject) {
    let tr = document.createElement('TR');
    let td, tdText;
    for (let value of Object.values(rows)) {
        td = document.createElement("TD");
        td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(value));
        tr.appendChild(td);
    }
    tbody.appendChild(tr);
};
```

```html
<table>
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <td>Item</td>
         <td>Description</td>
         <td>Price</td>
         <td>Image</td>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody id="tbody">
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The `Object.keys` part is redundant. You can just use `forEach` right away

Comment: Hello @Nerdvoso, I'm not sure whether the code you provided would work not because I used the code provided by nickzoum and it resolvled what I was working on. Thank you for taking the time to help me out with this.

Comment: @ImCanaan Quiet, I wanted to give my own version to solve the problem. Maybe it could interest someone else.

Comment: @nickzoum I have modified, thanks for the constructive signaling

Comment: @Nerdvoso You are still using `in` instead of `of`. Are you doing this for ES5 compatibility?

Answer (score 0):

See this fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/j5mnto3g/2/

Create a table in Html

```
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr><th>Item Image</th><th>Item Name</th><th>Description</th><th>Price</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tbl-body"> </tbody>
</table>
```

and add row with in table by a simple for loop

```
var item = ["Chicken soup", "Chicken tacos", "Chicken quesadilla", "Chicken burrito", 
            "Chicken enchilada"];

var itemDescription = ["Delicious creamy chicken soup", "Homemade tacos", "Cheesy chicken quesadillas", "Hearty stuffed chicken burrito", "World famous chicken enchilada"];

var itemPrice = [14.99, 17.99, 15.75, 22.95, 12.55];

var imgArray = new Array();

imgArray[0] = new Image();
imgArray[0].src = 'chickensoup.jpg';

imgArray[1] = new Image();
imgArray[1].src = 'chickentaco.jpg';

imgArray[2] = new Image();
imgArray[2].src = 'chickenque.jpg';

imgArray[3] = new Image();
imgArray[3].src = 'chickenburrito.jpg';

imgArray[4] = new Image();
imgArray[4].src = 'chickenenchilada.jpg';
var rows = '';
for(i = 0; i < item.length; i++){
    rows += '<tr><td><img src="'+imgArray[i]+'" width="20" height="20"></td><td>'+item[i]+'</td><td>'+itemDescription[i]+'</td><td>'+itemPrice[i]+'</td></tr>';
}
document.getElementById('tbl-body').innerHTML = rows;
```

Use correct image path and size

Comment: Hello @Avi    I'm not sure why, but this did not resiolve it. nickzoum provided an example above that did do the trick. Thank you for your help. I appreciate you taking the time to help out.

Answer (score -1):

i wont show the whole code, but this is the best way to do this logically

```
//JS
let array = ["item 1", "item2"];

//start a string (of html)
let htmlDisplayed = "<div id='htmlString'><ul>";

//loop each array item as a list item
for (let i=0; i< array.length; i++) {
  htmlDisplayed = htmlDisplayed.concat(`<li>${array[i]}</li>`);
}

//close your html tags off
htmlDisplayed = htmlDisplayed.concat("</ul></div>");

//display it
document.getElementById("yourElement").innerHTML = htmlDisplayed;
```